# MVC MapRoute with parameter ticket-id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to create a route with an url like: "{controller}/{action}/{ticket-id}"

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "Auth/Login/{ticket-id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Login"}
);
```

I can't create the route because of the parameter name "ticket-id".

No problem with "ticketid"... but I can't change the parameter name.

Do you have any solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this anyway? It would be illegal to do the following: `public ActionResult Login(string ticket-id) {...}`

Comment: use `ticketId`. You can only use chars which are allowed in parameters too.

Answer (score 2):

MVC MapRoute maps the parameter name in the template to the parameter names in the action.

You say that you can't change the parameter name. Problem is that in c# you would not even be allowed to use that parameter name.

c# does not allow you to have hyphens `-` for parameter/variable names.

This would not be allowed as names must be valid identifiers.

```
public ActionResult Login(string ticket-id ) {...}
```